# How to get average value every hour in a day

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get average temperature value every hour in a day. so far, i only managed to only get the average temperature in a day (overall, not in every hour) using the AVG function. the data is dynamic so i can't do query to specify a time range. here's my table.

```
-----------------------------------------
| time          |   temprature          |
-----------------------------------------
| 2019-01-11 12:00:00   |   23          |
| 2019-01-11 12:20:00   |   24          |
| 2019-01-11 12:40:00   |   24          |
| 2019-01-11 13:00:00   |   25          |
| 2019-01-11 13:50:00   |   26          |
| 2019-01-11 14:12:00   |   25          |
| 2019-01-11 14:14:00   |   27          |
| 2019-01-11 14:14:00   |   27          |
| 2019-01-11 14:16:00   |   29          |
| 2019-01-11 14:18:00   |   30          |
| 2019-01-11 15:37:00   |   27          |
| 2019-01-11 16:00:00   |   24          |
```

this is the expected result of the returned query.

```
-------------------------------------
| time                  |temprature|
-----------------------------------
| 2019-01-11 12:00:00   |   23.6    |
| 2019-01-11 13:00:00   |   25.5    |
| 2019-01-11 14:00:00   |   27.6    |
| 2019-01-11 15:00:00   |   27      |
| 2019-01-11 16:00:00   |   24      |
```

Comment: Combine your daily average approach with `DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `DATE(time), HOUR(time)`:

```
SELECT DATE(time) AS date
     , HOUR(time) AS hour
     , AVG(temprature)
FROM t
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Or this:

```
SELECT time
     - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time) MINUTE
     - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time) SECOND AS date_hour
     , AVG(temprature)
FROM t
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: @rosyciks and future readers because MySQL 8.0 has disabled auto sorting of `GROUP BY` clauses you should add `ORDER BY GROUP BY DATE(time), HOUR(time)` to this query if the sorting matters which it does if i see the topicstarters expected results.. rosyciks and future readers besides because tables/results in SQL by definition are **orderless** you should **always** use a `ORDER BY` if you want to enforce a order

Comment: `GROUP BY 1, 2` Whats this?.. `GROUP BY 1, 2` is error prone what happens if you change the column select order without changing the numbers in the `GROUP BY` for example. It can happen fast if your query is large enough.. (Don't answer on this it was meant as a rhetorical question)